# Continue for loop every 3 iterations

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have one array with somes string(images paths) and I want to be able to make a for and continue the for every 3 iterations to make a slideshow with 3 images

Exemple : array : ["url1","url2","url3", "url4","url5","url6","url7"]

My code :

```
<% project.othersimages.forEach((img, index) => { %>
                <%if(index % 3 == 2) {%>
                    <div class="slideshow-container">


                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                <img src="/<%=img.url%>" style="width:30%">
                                <img src="/<%=img.url%>" style="width:30%">
                                <img src="/<%=img.url%>" style="width:30%">
                            </div>


                            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                        </div>
                <%}%>

                <%})%>
```

And I want the result to be like:

```
    <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="/url1" style="width:30%">
            <img src="/url2" style="width:30%">
            <img src="/url3" style="width:30%">
        </div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="/url4" style="width:30%">
            <img src="/url5" style="width:30%">
            <img src="/url6" style="width:30%">
        </div>
<div class="mySlides fade">
            <img src="/url7" style="width:30%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
```

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

My new code :

```
<%if (project.othersimages.length > 0) {%>
                <% for(let i = 1; i < (project.othersimages.length / 3)+1; i++) { %>

                <div class="slideshow-container">


                            <div class="mySlides fade">
                                <% for(let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

                                    if( project.othersimages[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x) ]) { %>
                                <img src="<% project.othersimages[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x) ] %>" style="width:30%">
                                <% } %>

                                <% } %>
                            </div>


                            <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                        </div>
                    <%}%>
            <%}%>
```

console.log of otherimages :

```
"othersimages" : [ 
        "project-WhatsApp Image 2019-03-17 at 11.15.55.jpeg", 
        "project-WhatsApp Image 2019-03-17 at 11.15.56.jpeg", 
        "project-WhatsApp Video 2019-03-09 at 16.45.43.mp4", 
        "project-WhatsApp Video 2019-03-17 at 11.15.51.mp4"
    ],
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use Javascript to create a slideshow? I don't see any javascript code in your example.

Comment: You will need to use a counter

Comment: What work have you done towards solving the problem?

Comment: My slideshow is working, that's not the problem, i just want to iterate every 3 urls

Comment: i edited my post to be more clear

Comment: I don't see any javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

You can use two `for` loops and an internal check to make sure the array item exists.

I don't know what templating system you're using, so I'm not sure how to grab variables.

If you're using `<% javascript %>` for conditionals and `<%= variable %>` for getting variables, in the example code that follows you'll want to change this:

```
<img src="<% array[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x)) ] %>" style="width:30%">
```

to this:

```
 <img src="<%= array[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x))] %>" style="width:30%">
```

---

### Example:

```
<% for(let i = 1; i < (array.length / 3)+1; i++) { %>

<div class="mySlides fade">

<% for(let x = 0; x < 3; x++) { 

  if( array[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x)) ]) { %>
     <img src="<% array[ (((i*3) - 3 ) + x)) ] %>" style="width:30%">
   <% } %>

  <% } %>
 </div>

 <% } %>
```

Comment: Look good thanks :) I just have this error : 
@zfrish
<img src="(unknow)" style="width:30%">

Comment: any suggestions @zfrisch ?

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé did you try altering the template for the variable?

Comment: what do you mean by alterning ?

Comment: @BenjaminBarbé did you change <% %> to <%= %> ?

Answer (score 0):

What about the index argument of [foreach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Syntax) and mod(%) operator?

```
array.forEach((img, index) => {
    if(index % 3 == 2) {
        console.log("i am the third. index : " + index);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pull in the array indices and use the modulus to determine the output

```
let data=['url','url2','url3','url4','url5','url6','url7','url8'];

data.forEach((item,key)=>{

  if(key %3==0){
    //output the div starting tag
  }

  //output the array element as img

  if(key %3 ==0){
    //output the div closing tag
  }

})
```